# No posts information instead 404 error

Tags: django

How to display information that there is no post instead 404 error?

How often does something like this in django?

```
def post_by_category(request, slug):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
    categories = category.get_descendants(include_self=True)
    posts = get_list_or_404(Post, category__in=categories)

    return render_to_response("by_category.html",
                              {'posts': posts, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `posts = get_list_or_404(Post, category__in=categories)` you're explicitly *asking* it to return a 404 in case there are no posts.

Try:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(category__in=categories)
if posts:
    return render_to_response("by_category.html",
                              {'posts': posts}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    return render_to_response("by_category.html",
                              {'message': 'No posts found!'}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And make sure you print out the error {{ message }} inside `by_category.html`.

Comment: I try in my template: {% if posts %} posts  {% else %} No post {% endif %}. It also works. Where better to do: in views or in template? Thanks

Comment: If you're using the same template, you should implement this within the template itself.

Answer (score 1):

[`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) is just a convenience shortcut whose main purpose is to raise a `Http404`.

So, if you *don't want to raise* a 404 (i think that is your question) then you simply shouldn't use the shortcut but handle the situation yourself.

Something along these lines:

```
def my_view(request):
    try:
        my_object = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
    except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
        # render whatever you like
```